# Prevent Footer content from moving when browser window resized

Tags: html, css

I've looked at many a thread and understand the width and display tags ( min, max, block inline, inline-block and table etc), but I'm having a terrible time trying to fix this issue with my page footer.  When I resize the browser window, everything in the footer collapses.

Can someone kindly check my markup and let me know what I need to add in my CSS to fix this, please.

Basically I'd like the browser window to pass over the content and all that contained be fixed centrally... how it looks, laid out, when window full-size.

Thanks!

Site: http://mixititb.com/Z_Test_Site/index.html

Edit;

Two issues I'm seeing are when you change window size, the footer itself is collapsing and perhaps making the content bunch up.  So, that would be first priority fix and then aligning the content center.

For these two issues, I'm really stuck and truly appreciate the help for a newbie to get this fixed.  Thanks for checking my code!

Edit 2;

Just fixed the footer sizing with overflow-x: hidden; for the fix_footer class! :)

So, now we/I just have to figure out why the content is collapsing when you resize the window.  Any takers? :) :)

Edit 3;

@ PeeHaa, easwee, mario, user35443, Starkeen... please kindly take this off hold, I'm unsure how to edit the question as I've fixed some issues myself and too with help from those below, but a few remain, so didn't want to ask another question.  Thanks, appreciated!

Edit 4;

Fixed through reorganising HTML structuring div's with classes and setting .container to white instead of the footer itself.  Setting all main div's (i.e. nav, content and footer) with a class of container allowed fixed scaling of the footer as it was taking the width set in CSS.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but could you re-phrase your question, Im not sure what you're asking for, from the looks of the website, you want it to align in the middle ?

Comment: Hi,

Yes, all the content in the footer should be center aligned, but as you can see from the CSS I have a few things going on for the form, icons and navigation links aligning too.  So, I want all that as a block to be aligned center and nothing in it flex/collapse/bunch up when you change the browser window size... which is what happens currently.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: post what you have so far, SO is not about providing complete solutions.

Comment: You can set a `min-width` style on your `footer` div so it never collapses beyond a certain width

Comment: Mladen, it should just be a re-order of the markup and CSS for aligning I think and can be viewed by source.  To post, should I click answer question, as comments here don't space out...?

Jonathan, I've tried min-width but the content itself collapses.

Thanks, very much appreciate the quick replies all :)

Comment: P.s. I've been using http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ to check on sizing for various monitors and mobile devices, and wish to make it work on all.  I'm a newbie, but pleased to have fixed many an issue... just not this :)

Comment: Don't click answer unless you have _an answer_. Edit your question to include the information, as if it was always there (no "EDIT:" please). It'll help if you make the example that shows the problem as short as possible.

Comment: If you're designing for multiple devices, altering the footer styles using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) is something you may want to look into.  This way the footer can be intentionally designed for different devices instead of trying to make it a "one size fits all" solution

Comment: Just tried media queries from answer below but no joy, have updated the question for seeing two issues linked...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search media queries on google and center the elements with text-align: center or margin: 0 auto,  if the elem are floated, use clearfix.

Your footer breaks at about 900px.

Example:

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    center your elem
}

Comment: Just tried this, placing in .fix_footer and it didn't work, everything still collapses.  Also when you make the screen size smaller as well as content collapsing so does the footer itself... So if you change size and then scroll horizontally you'll see the footer size is changing.

Two issues I think.  Any ideas? :)

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 900px) { center your elem }

Comment: your elem in the footer are not floated. Use some media queries and will work....

Comment: Edited main question.  Fixed footer size, just need to fix content.  Not sure what you mean exactly, though I know how to float left, but then can I centre the content with text align or margin auto?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I could use media queries, but am unsure of the code itself I'd need to type specifically...?  And, media queries I believe aren't supported for lower version browsers, for example lower than IE 9 (which most may be using? - I'm not entirely sure of percent use for browsers these days).

Comment: It works with media queries, they are not supported lower than IE8(http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20media) and  you should really check your html and css. Remove the fixed position on #footer and add a inner-footer class on the empty div in the footer, add the last css rules from jsFiddle and play with the media query width size. This is just an improvisation, you should change your markup and css   https://jsfiddle.net/2n69vvL4/

Comment: Thanks!  That doesn't really work as expected as you have to set a width as far as I know, and having tested the page with iPad it throws the footer all the way to the left and leaves a gap to the right.

Any others ideas?  Really appreciate the help! :)  Thank you.

Comment: Example: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//mixititb.com/Z_Test_Site/index.html&w=768&h=1024&a=22&s=1

Checking smaller sizes for the site with quirktools, say 10" through 13", have the footer chopped to a size, leaving gap to the right.

We're nearly there, just not quite...

Is there anything that can be done with display: table; to fix the position and not have it size?

Comment: You will have to add more media queries for every device size and play with the margin value. Do you want to make your website responsive? Or just for desktop??

Comment: I'll look into it today and get back to you...

Comment: Thanks Cristian, you rock!

I've managed to fix the collapsing, but using another demo site from a Udemy tutorial - http://mixititb.com/Z_Test_Site2/index.html

Unsure how to fix my markup to reflect the demo layout?

In demo I have the same issue with both the hero yellow background and footer background in CSS collapsing to the size of the window and not the body, which is because they all have the class: container, a fixed width.

I think this is where the fix lies, but am unsure how to proceed.  Can there be a Media Query to force the background images the size of the body/html?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/ykanza8a/ and tell me what you think, the forms are not done for desktop view. Do you know Twitter Bootstrap? It is a lot easier if you use it

Comment: The site needs to be structured/viewed as posted, with the footer fixed and nav/icons etc aligned.  The only issue I'm having as I say for the "Site2" is the background images are collapsing on resizing the window.  Getting that fixed I can perhaps work from there for the design. :)  I'm aware a little of Bootstrap, but don't wish to code using that to then expand for others... as another learning curve... needing to get up and running asap.  Thanks for the help, hoping the background issue is an easy(ish) fix if you can kindly help.

Comment: The background image (just that, not content) for the footer needs to be equal to the body width/window size dynamically, so it's not clipped.

Comment: I don't mind people scrolling left/right on devices or zooming in, just not a huge fan of the flex design approach (personal pref).

Comment: I think I've fixed it!  Instead of having the whole footer have a white background, I've set the container to white (with the box shadow).  Each main div is has a class of container, and they all have the same width... so there's no problems as far as I can tell with alignment.  Check it out and let me know if you notice any errors... http://mixititb.com/Z_Test_Site2/index.html

Comment: Great job, works fine. But the mobile view is not so great because of the fixed size, try to make it responsive when you have some free time.

Comment: Awesome, really glad to have fixed it, and can't thank you enough and all here for the support.  I'll definitely think about the mobile site when I'm ready to rock, I think I can do some media query stuff for that (right?), to see what device a user is using to direct them to the correct layout...?  Cheers again! :)

Comment: Glad to help. Media queries all the way.....  :)

Comment: Cool!  Time to read up... :wink: :)